# jQuery UI Incorrect replacemenet of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, user-interface, global

When using jQuery UI in one of my appliations, I get a strange error. I use a general function to open my Dialogs, it's called  `OpenDialog()`

Here is the code:

```
function OpenDialog(href,parameters,width,botoes,dialog_name,dialog_id,modal,onOpen,onClose) 
{
    load("start");
    _id = dialog_id+'_'+Date.now();

    $.post(href,parameters, function(data){
        $(data).dialog({
            title               :   dialog_name,
            draggable           :   (modal) ? false : true,
            modal               :   modal,
            resizable           :   (modal) ? false : true,
            dialogClass         :   'dialog',
            width               :   width+'px',
            close               :   function(event,ui){
                                        if (typeof onClose !== 'undefined' && onClose !== false) { onClose(); }
                                        $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();                                                 
                                    },
            open                :   function(event,ui) {
                                        $(this).attr("id",_id);
                                        _id='#'+_id;
                                        if (typeof onOpen !== 'undefined' && onOpen !== false) { onOpen(_id); }
                                        execMaskOntoThis(_id);
                                        load("end");
                                    },
            buttons             :   botoes
        });
    });
}
```

So, when I create a new dialog, it generates for me an unique id for that. My problem is, when I use the variable _id for some buttons, something messes up and the 'event' is shown on the last openned dialog.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any tips about how to control unique values within dialogs using my function?

Comment: Why are you declaring `_id` as a global variable?

Comment: @Shmiddty That's probably the majority of the problem here.

Comment: @LuizFelipe But you are. If you don't precede the variable with `var` it will go to the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function OpenDialog(href,parameters,width,botoes,dialog_name,dialog_id,modal,onOpen,onClose) 
{
    load("start");
    var _id = dialog_id+'_'+Date.now(); // _id is now part of the local scope of OpenDialog

    $.post(href,parameters, function(data){
        $(data).dialog({
            title               :   dialog_name,
            draggable           :   (modal) ? false : true,
            modal               :   modal,
            resizable           :   (modal) ? false : true,
            dialogClass         :   'dialog',
            width               :   width+'px',
            close               :   function(event,ui){
                                        if (typeof onClose !== 'undefined' && onClose !== false) { onClose(); }
                                        $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();                                                 
                                    },
            open                :   function(event,ui) {
                                        $(this).attr("id",_id);
                                        _id='#'+_id;
                                        if (typeof onOpen !== 'undefined' && onOpen !== false) { onOpen(_id); }
                                        execMaskOntoThis(_id);
                                        load("end");
                                    },
            buttons             :   botoes
        });
    });
}
```